# Can anyone identify these Batman minifigures?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

Can anyone tell me something about these minifigures?
Are they custom-made or perhaps fake? I could find nothing about them.

[image]

Comment: What is the source of these pictures? First one seems to be released for some special occasion, like some other minifigs with logo on the back.

Comment: The pictures are from a seller. Acording to him these minifigures are 2016 prototypes. I had oportunity to check the black one and indeed all pieces has LEGO brand mark. About the blue one I found an ebay post where shows it but i think it's lost https://picclick.com/LEGO-Batman-Dark-Blue-Prototype-2016-Polybag-Design-202621306775.html

Answer (score 2):

After scouring [all of the Batman minifigures catalogized by Brickset](https://brickset.com/minifigs?query=batman), I couldn't find any exact matches for any of the two torsos, but it is just as possible that these particular figures are not indexed by Brickset or have some kind of other name.

The wings of the right one seem peculiar to me, I suspect they are non-genuine.

Higher resolution photos could be helpful for further investigation, or you could check for the LEGO trademarks on each piece (they are usually hidden inside or on the underside) to determine if the base plastic pieces are genuine. If they are, the printing might still be 3rd party.